# NGINX load balancing adjust proxy_pass URL based on the upstream server

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have basic nginx load-balancing setup in place, e.g.

```
http {
  ... ## some stuff, log formats, etc.
  upstream backend {
    server localhost:8001
    server localhost:8002
  }
  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name foo.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://backend/foo/bar/;
    }
  }
}
```

But I'd like to parameterize the `proxy_pass` URL with a value/variable that's specific to the chosen upstream server. For example, if the server with port 8001 is selected, I'd like to use `proxy_pass http://backend/foo/bar/8001`, and likewise if the server with port 8002 is selected, I'd like to use `proxy_pass http://backend/foo/bar/8002` (where `backend` is obviously replaced by the selected server name, as per nginx's usual load-balancing setup).

Does anyone know if this is possible?

(I know I could do some self-routing within nginx to achieve this ... e.g. setting up two new nginx addresses that are the upstreams, then `proxy_pass` each one of those individually, but I'm wondering if there's a way to dynamically rewrite the URL passed to the upstream server *after* the next upstream server to try has been selected by the load-balancing system.)

Comment: This goes against the idea of load balancing, where each replica is supposed to be exactly like all others. May I ask for the reason you want to do this? For me it seems like it would be the task of your upstream software to manage this.

Comment: I'm stuck using an upstream server that does its own 'smart' mapping of traffic from various ports to backend processes. Even if this upstream server listens on multiple ports, if the requests are for the same final resource, the same backend process is used (this part is out of my control), but I'd like to distribute the load across processes. So, I'd like to 'duplicate' the eventual requested resource (the `/8001`, `/8002` suffixes in the example) ... in reality, no duplication is happening, since these are just symlinks to the same actual resource.

Comment: FWIW, I've already gotten this working with a specific configuration of the upstream server, but I was hoping to make this setup a bit easier to maintain with the nginx trick in the original question, if it's doable.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that you do not actually have to use different ports and it is instead sufficient to send everything to the same port, but use different paths? Obviously you cannot do this using the upstream-load-balancing mechanism, but you can for example use geo-mapping to match specific subnets to one path and others to the other and do load balancing based on client IPs that way.  IF I am correct and this approach would work, I can provide an example-confdig in an answer.